# SQL Server CE : alter column Token in error = DEFAULT

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server CE and I have a table `[accounts]`. I was modifying the column `[ondate]` so that it can have a default of `GetDate`.

My query is

```
ALTER TABLE [accounts] 
  ALTER COLUMN [ondate] DATETIME NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

But I get this error :

> Token in error = DEFAULT

I have tried `getdate` without parenthesis, with single quotes (') but the error is still the same.

How to modify the column `[ondate]` to have default of `getdate`?

Comment: Where is `Constraint`?

Comment: it is sqlce, it works fine without constraints. But i would be better to use constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD DEFAULT getdate() FOR [ondate]
```

It is always better to add a name to `constraints`

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD CONSTRAINT DF_ONDATE_GETDATE DEFAULT getdate() FOR [ondate]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
Alter Table [accounts] ADD DEFAULT getdate() for [ondate]
```

Comment: Duplicate of my answer ;)

Comment: I thought i would be better to use same table as OP asked.